# Express.js _ How do I use two static views directories?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple directories to serve view files in my app, but everything I have tried is not working, including responses I've seen on posts here.  Please help.  More directories is cooler right?  Lol. It's just that it it provides for better organization and separation of files, improving app efficiency and security.

Here's what I want.

`app.use(express.static('/Users/matt/Desktop/websites/app10.14.2020/views')); app.use(express.static('/Users/matt/Desktop/websites/app10.14.2020/views2'));`

When I run this, only the first directory specified (views not views2) seems to be accessible.  I want files to be served from both.  Please advise and happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

the localhost:PORT/ opens view1.html
the localhost:PORT/view2 opens view2.html

```
   const app = express()
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "view1.html"))
   })
   app.get('/view2',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "view2.html"))
   })
```

According to what is written here, there is only an error in the url section.
You should examine
https://expressjs.com/tr/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('files'))
```

OR

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: I think you confused what I'm asking.  I am trying to serve files from two different directories (views and views2) not html files and btw I actually use ejs not html.  For some reason I cannot seem to get my app to read these files from two different directories, one called views one called views2.  Each of those contain multiple ejs files (effectively html) that often contain numerous lines with hrefs.  The files work seamlessly when served from 1 directory, but I cannot get both to serve.

Comment: Again, I am trying to serve files from both directories `app.use(express.static('/Users/matt/Desktop/websites/app10.14.2020/views'));
app.use(express.static('/Users/matt/Desktop/websites/app10.14.2020/views2'));` the only one that is serving when I run nodemon is views not views2.

Comment: This doesnt work, for lone thing the css files are not served and also the 2nd directory is still not being able to serve

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are serving statics are right.
Just verify if the name of paths is correct, I recommend to use `__dirname` and `path.resolve` to resolve the path of statics, example:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'./static1')))
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'./static2')))
```

Remember to name your files with different names, otherwise express ignore the second file with same name... or create paths for each static path, like:

```js
app.use('/static1', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'./static1')))
app.use('/static2', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'./static2')))
```

Comment: I entered and saved the code you recommended but with the correct names (views and views2) but it crashed the app.

Comment: What is the error? Could you post the folder organization? like:
`root
|- index.js
|- views
|-- view1.ejs
|- views2
|-- view2.ejs`